# Java Null Pointer Exception on JLIST

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception, jlist

OK so I'm trying to output the current string from an array that was put into a list...
However when I click on the list I get a NullPointerException... :\

Help? :)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class lisTry extends JApplet implements MouseListener {

public static String newline;
public static JList list;

    public void init() {

            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            listModel.addElement("Debbie Scott");
            listModel.addElement("Scott Hommel");
            listModel.addElement("Alan Sommerer");

            JList list = new JList(listModel);


        this.getContentPane().add(list);

        list.addMouseListener(this);

        String newline = "\n";

        list.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
       System.out.println("You clicked on: " + index);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just a note: `>` is used for marking up blockquotes; to mark up code you indent your snippets by 4 spaces. (I've made this change for you.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
JList list = new JList(listModel);
```

into this line:

```
list = new JList(listModel);
```

You are creating a local variable `list` in your constructor and thus hide the `list` field of your class. So the field `lisTry.list` stays null, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That returns the number in the array not name :\

Comment: Yes, because you call getSelectedIndex(), which returns the index. See Java API docs. When you want to see the list item text itself, call getSelectedValue() instead.